# combine strings and convert to time of sql server using c# or jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, sql-server-2008

I have two dropdowns for `startHour`, `startMinute`.Now i need to take selected hour and minute from dropdown and save in sql as time(7) datatype. How can i convert data using c# or jquery?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

- Pass the data however you want from the client to your C# code.
- Create a `TimeSpan` in your C# code, as per [this mapping table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)
- Insert the value into the database using parameterized SQL

Do *not* try to pass the value as a string in your SQL; *always* use parameterized SQL, which avoids potentially incorrect conversions and SQL injection attacks.